# Using QLockFile::setStaleLockTime() but lock doesn't become stale?

Tags: c++, qt, locking

I'm setting the stale lock time to 100 ms using this code:

```
QLockFile lock1(fn);
lock1.setStaleLockTime(100);
QVERIFY(lock1.lock());

QLockFile lock2(fn);
lock2.setStaleLockTime(100);
QVERIFY(lock2.lock());
```

I expected it to block for only 100ms, but it blocks indefinitely. Why is that?

Am I misunderstanding how lock files should become stale? Here's [what the docs say](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlockfile.html#setStaleLockTime):

> The value of staleLockTime is used by lock() and tryLock() in order to determine when an existing lock file is considered stale, i.e. left over by a crashed process. This is useful for the case where the PID got reused meanwhile, so one way to detect a stale lock file is by the fact that it has been around for a long time.

Comment: I tried to learn Qt docs and sources. So it looks like a bug. Create bugreport https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67909.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand something

> If the process holding the lock crashes, the lock file stays on disk
>   and can prevent any other process from accessing the shared resource,
>   ever. For this reason, QLockFile tries to detect such a "stale" lock
>   file, based on the process ID written into the file. To cover the
>   situation that the process ID got reused meanwhile, the current
>   process name is compared to the name of the process that corresponds
>   to the process ID from the lock file. If the process names differ, the
>   lock file is considered stale. Additionally, the last modification
>   time of the lock file (30s by default, for the use case of a
>   short-lived operation) is taken into account. If the lock file is
>   found to be stale, it will be deleted.

So not only `staleLockTime` but also process ID checked and other things. So you can't use this method such way.

Comment: But I thought that because of PID reuse, PID can only be used to prove the file is stale without the need to wait. It's impossible to prove the file is not stale by PID only (it might have been reused).